# @Path works, but @RequestMapping doesn't Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-rs

This works, I am able to make a request in postman for this Service.

```java
@RestController
@Path("sample")
public class SampleClass {

        @GET
    @Path(value = "/s1")
    public Object get() {
        //Something
    }
    
}
```

The problem is when I try to use `@RequestMapping` instead of `@Path`, I get a

> 404 Not Found

Error.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("sample")
public class CommonService {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/s1", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object get() {
        //Something
    }
    
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: change it to "/sample" and see?

Comment: Already tried, no luck...

Comment: am still almost sure that its related to the leading "/" in the sample , the 2nd part of code looks ok , but the sample with no "/" look troubling to me .

Comment: `@Path` and `@GET` are not Spring MVC annotations. You must be using some other web framework.

Answer (score 2):

After a while, I found out that for the JAX-RS (@Path) I had configured in web.xml file a different route "something".
JAX-RS: localhost:8080**/something**/sample/s1
Spring Rest Services: localhost:8080/sample/s1

I was also missing a "/" in the Spring Rest Service.
@RequestMapping("**/**sample")

Full code bellow:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class CommonService {
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/s1", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object get() {
        //Something
    }
    
}
```